# minify javascript with just alphanumeric charset

Tags: javascript, vite, minify, uglifier

I'm writing a frontend component with `React` and build it with `vite.js`.

This frontend component can sit on multiple pages with different libraries. As it's very common other libraries use `'$'` (Like `jQuery`); when minifying, I want the final result don't use or touch anything with `'$'`.

When I don't use minification, there is no `'$'`; it's introduced in the minification process.

I've tried multiple `Vite` configs, even nameCache option in `terser`, but no luck.

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am struggling with the same problem.